# Which types of prepositional phrase is "toward its employees" in Philosophy guiding the organization's policies towards its employees is not bad?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases

> 1. The philosophy that guides the organization's policies towards its employees is not bad.
> 2. The philosophy  guiding the organization's policies towards its employees is not bad.
> 3. The organization's policies towards its employees is not bad.

In the first sentence, the phrase *towards its employees* is an adverbial prepositional phrase acting as an adverb which modifies the finite verb *guide*, isn't it?

In the third sentence, the phrase *towards its employees* is an adjectival prepositional phrase acting as an adjective which modifies the *organigation's policies* isn't it?

In the second sentence, *guiding the organization's policies towards its employees* is a participle phrase acting as an adjective which modifies the *philosophy, isn't it?

But my question is about the phrase *towards its employees* in the second sentence. I don't know whether it (towards its employees) is an adjectival prepositional phrase which modifies the *organization's policies* or an adverbial preposition phrase which modifies the word *guiding* in the second sentence.

Comment: I think that the phrase modifies the word "policies" in all cases, because it would seem illogical if it modified "guides".

Comment: In your opinion, "toward its empolyees" is an adjectival prepositional phrase in all the three sentences isn't it?

Comment: The philosophy guides the organization's policies toward its empolyees. In this sentence, "toward its empolyees" modifies the word "guide(finite verb)" isn't it? @CowperKettle

Comment: MdHasem: No. Prepositional element "toward its employees" modifies ***policies*** (policies aimed at / concerned with *employees* as opposed to policies concerned with *customers*, for example). It wouldn't make sense to talk about those policies being ***guided*** towards *anything* - policies don't even "move" at all, so they can't be "guided / led" anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

> The boy guides the boat towards the shore.

In this sentence, "towards the shore" modifies "guides"

> The philosophy guides the policy towards employees.

In this sentence, "towards employees" modifies "policy", because you cannot *move* a policy physically closer to employees - the word "guides" just has two different senses in sentence 1 and sentence 2.

Answer (score 4):

> *The philosophy guiding* [*the organization's policies towards its
>   employees*] *is not bad.*

I think the more salient interpretation is that it's "the organization's policies towards its employees" that are being guided by a philosophy that is not too bad.

Which means that the PP "towards its employees" modifies "policies", and thus the whole bracketed element is a noun phrase functioning as direct object of "guiding".

Note: it could be argued that the PP is not a modifier but a complement.

Answer (score 4):

In these sentences, the word "toward" doesn't refer to a direction. It's a synonym for "regarding", and is used to modify "policies". So "policies toward its employees" refers to the policies the company makes regarding their employees, and "towards its employees" is being used as an adjectival prepositional phrase.

Most online dictionaries don't mention this sense, but I found it in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/towards):

> 2.b:  in relation to
>   *an attitude toward life*

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes, the second sentence is syntactically ambiguous and could be viewed either way. However, as a native speaker just reading the sentence, my interpretation agrees with that of CowperKettle--namely, I interpret *towards its employees* as a modifier of *policies* in all three sentences.

Comment: The philosophy guides the organization's policies toward its empolyees. In this sentence, "toward its empolyees" modifies the word "guide(finite verb)" isn't it?

Comment: In your opinion, "toward its empolyees" is an adjectival prepositional phrase in all the three sentences isn't it?